# How to fetch initial data using provider in flutter effectievly

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

Recently, I did a flutter course.
The instructor was making the get request from an API so difficult. For a hybrid framework like flutter I never thought it's so difficult.

Below is my code. I am using `provider` for state management.

```
Future<void> fetchAndSetProducts() async {
    try {
      const url = 'fetch-url';
      final response = await http.get(url);
      final data = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
      final List<Product> loadedProducts = [];
      data.forEach((key, value) {
        loadedProducts.add(Product(
          id: key,
          title: value['title'],
          description: value['description'],
          imageUrl: value['imageUrl'],
          price: value['price'],
          isFavorite: value['isFavorite'],
        ));
      });

      _items = loadedProducts;
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (error) {
      throw (error);
    }
  }
```

And in the products overview screen were I am showing the products page this method is called like below:

```
bool _isInit = true;
  bool _isLoading = false;

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    if (_isInit) {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = true;
      });
      Provider.of<Products>(context).fetchAndSetProducts().then((_) => {
            setState(() {
              _isLoading = false;
            })
          });
    }
    _isInit = false;
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }
```

The other method included a sneaky way of using duration of zero just like we use in JavaScript set timeout giving a zero time.

It's worth noting that in `didChangeDependencies` we could not use async await, so most probably a call back hell awaits.
Also a variable needs to be initialized just for calling the API once upon loading.

Is there no easy solution to this? Or an industry way of dealing with this?

Comment: It is an 1M $ question....i was in the same situation 3 months back and left provider for https://github.com/GIfatahTH/states_rebuilder

Comment: any good on this ? I mean i don't want to learn all the state management libraries in the world

Comment: there are over 20 state managements libraries. A nightmare. I just stuck with that coming from the same problem. Just look at this how it handles the state https://github.com/GIfatahTH/states_rebuilder/wiki/WhenRebuilder-and-WhenRebuilderOr

Answer (score 7):

[here is a minimal working example of what you can do](https://github.com/byshy/state_management_session), it's not the best thing in the world, but this is what works for me, let me know if you can make it any better.

The answer to your problem is really simple, BUT, you need to rearrange some stuff first.

A Flutter app can be split into multiple layers which are (just for example) data, state management and UI, in the data layer you will have all methods that communicate with the API, and you call them inside the state management solution (which is provider in your case), the result will be accessible from the provider which will save the data in a variable, then the UI will be able to retrieve these data from the provider, this seems a bit redundant I know, but there is a reason why we do that, if you put the API call inside the provider itself, and there is somewhere else in your app that uses the same endpoint then you will have duplicate code, as for the provider, it's the place where your data is stored in the runtime, these data are what makes the state of your app, finally, the UI can handle displaying data from the provider easily, just make a boolean in the provider that indicates if the API call is executing/loading or not, and inside the consumer in the UI display different widgets based on the boolean.

If we were to visualize the flow of the operation it would be like this:
1- action from the UI that triggers a method from the provider.
2- inside the provider method you will set the boolean indicating that the API call is executing to true and call notifyListeners().
3- call the API request and call .then() on it.
4- inside the .then() set the boolean to false to notify that the call is over and set the received data to a variable inside the provider and call notifyListeners again.
5- in the UI you should have a consumer listening to your provider and handling the boolean, if its true then display a `CircularProgressIndicator` for example, and if it's false then display your desired widget

---

Regarding the context in the initState you can fix this problem in 3 ways:
1- using WidgetsBinding.instance
.addPostFrameCallback((_) => yourProviderFunction(context));
2- by registering your provider in a service locator so you don't have to use a context at all. (which is what I used in the example project I posted above)
3- by executing the desired function in the constructor of the provider, so when its initialized the API request will be called

Comment: Great answer Basel. I used #3 and it solved a problem I was having. Thank you.

Comment: I am trying to do #3 but I cant figure out how, because the request is async and I dont see a way to await it. How did you do it?

Comment: @L.Heinrichs you can find your request in state_management_session/lib/features/products/products_provider.dart line 38 in the example listed above

Comment: Yes I managed to fire the request eventually.
I guess my problem is more that the provider needs data from another provider (Auth) and I am not sure how to link them both properly, but that is not really related to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Is this the Academind course?

Also this is the correct way.

For using a Provider you need the context.

**EDIT: Added BaselAbuhadrous' comment to the answer.**

You need to use `didChangeDependencies` because the `initState` actually provides the context, but the screen layout isn't built yet, so you get an error, but if you used `WidgetsBindings.instance` and call the provider inside of it, then you won't get the error.

Comment: Will, I'ld like to correct the context part of this answer, the initState actually provides the context, but the screen layout isn't built yet, so you get an error, but if you used WidgetsBindings.instance and call the provider inside of it, then you won't get the error

Comment: @BaselAbuhadrous thanks for that, I also am relatively new to flutter didn't know that.

Comment: how to use widgetbindings? And why is it so complicated and stuff. i understand the comment about context not being there since layout is not built, but why we need to have a varible isInit that checks whether it's loaded or not?

Comment: We need the variable because unlike initState didChangeDependencies is called multiple times, so you'll have the same data added to your list again and again. Also I won't be able to help with WidgetsBindings, as I myself don't know how to use it.

Comment: @basel can you help?

Comment: @Jithin hope the answer I posted helps

Answer (score 0):

```
  //your model , product_model.dart
  import 'dart:convert';

   List<Product> availableTicketsFromJson(String str) => List<Product>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Product.fromJson(x)));

  class Product {
  String title;
  String description;
  String imageUrl;
  double price;
  bool isFavorite;

  Product(
      {this.title,
      this.description,
      this.imageUrl,
      this.price,
      this.isFavorite});

  factory Product.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Product(
        title: json['title'] as String,
        description: json['description'] as String,
        imageUrl: json['imageUrl'] as String,
        price: json['price'] as double,
        isFavorite: json['isFavorite'] as bool,
      );
}



 //viewmodel class
 final String url = "test.com";
 Future<List<Product> fetchProducts() async {
 List<Product> products = List<Product>();
 try {
       final request = await http.get(url);
       if(request.statusCode == 200) {
            products = productsFromJson(request.body.toString());
            notifyListeners();
         } else {
            print(request.statusCode.toString());
         }
    } catch(e) {
      return List<Product>();
    }
    return products;
 } 
 

 //fetch_data.dart
 Create your instance of provider in the page that you wanna fetch the data:
 Under State<yourWidget>

 => FetchDataViewModel _model;
    List<Product> products = [];
 under build method
 => _model = Provider.of<FetchDataViewModel>(context,listen: false);

    Make a http request with FutureBuilder
    FutureBuilder(future:_model.fetchProducts()),
    builder: (context,snapshot)){
       if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
       products = snapshot.data;
       if(products.length > 0) {
           return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: products.length,
              itemBuilder : (context,index) {
               return _items();
           }
         );
      } else {return _noSavedDataWidget();}
     }
    }

    You can test such a code
```

Comment: isn't this more complicated now?

Comment: First we created our model in another dart file so that we can have our special methods for this model in it then created a new file which is view model to make http request to the api service with that way your ui will not know anything about what happens between ui and http requests after all when you want to make http requests just create and instance of your provider then put your methods where you need them.

Comment: For a simple application it can seem complicated but when your application starts grows up it will be maintainable and clear to read and write

Comment: By the way for now we don't have api class normally you should create it as i said explained

Answer (score -2):

sometimes

Provider.of<'providerClassName'>(context, **listen : false**).'providerFunction'

might help.

Comment: Appreciate the effort bro, but this wasn't the need of the solution.